# Why am I getting a 404 error when trying to upload an image using Node.js/Express.js API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs/Expressjs, Right now i am trying to "upload image" using API, But whenever i hit/use function in "postman" then giving me 404 error,even nothing display in "console.log",Here is my current function

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const saveImageToDatabase = async (filename) => {
  console.log('file uploaded');
  try {
    // Simulating saving image to the database
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log(`Saved ${filename} to the database`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving image to the database:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    consloe.log('i am hereeeeeee');
  try {
    const file = req.file;

    if (!file) {
        console.log('no file uploaded');
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
      return;
    }

    await saveImageToDatabase(file.filename);

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'File uploaded and saved successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while uploading the file' });
  }
});
```

And i am using following link in postman with "image" parameter (api is controller name)

```
localhost:3000/api/upload
```

Comment: This means your routing isn't set up properly, but you're not showing how your controller is connected to Express.